# Statistics: Probability Distribution

Tags: statistics

**1) The discrete random variable R has Probability density function  P(R=r)=c(3-r)  for r=0,1,2,3.**

**a,    Find the value of the constant c**

**b,    Draw the probability distribution of R.**

*My Solution For Part a :*

P(R=0) = C(3-0) = 3C

P(R=1) = C(3-1) = 2C

P(R=2) = C(3-2) = 1C

P(R=3) = C(3-3) = 0C

3C + 2C + 1C + 0 = 1

*6C = 1*

*= 1/6*

*I do not understand Part B of the question and will appreciate some assistance. Have I done part A correctly ?*

---

**2) A discrete random variable X has a probability distribution as shown in the table.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jsDV.png

**a)    Find the value of a**

**b)    Find P(X>4)**

**c)    Find P(X ≤2)**

**d)    Find P(2≤x≤5)**

*My Solutions:*

0.1 + 0.3 + 0.2 + 0.05 + a = 1

0.65 + 1 = a

a = 1 - 0.65 = 0.35

a = 0.36 or 7/20

*NB: I converted them to decimals but they both add up to the same answer*

*b,*  1/20

*c,*  1/10 + 3/10 =  2/5

*d,*  3/10 + 7/20 + 1/5 + 1/20 = 9/10

*I will like this question checked over to see if I have done it correctly, thank you.*

Answer (score 1):

You've already got most of the answer to question `b` in your answer to question `a`:

- $P(R=0) = C(3-0) = 3C=3\times(1/6)=0.5$
- $P(R=1) = C(3-1) = 2C=2\times(1/6)=0.33333$
- $P(R=2) = C(3-2) = 1C=1\times(1/6)=0.16667$
- $P(R=3) = C(3-3) = 0C=0\times(1/6)=0$

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my question 2 is correct ?

Comment: @Ken: You should publish it as a separate question. $0.36\neq7/20$. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For part b, you can draw 2D plot which has x axis is R (from 0 to 3) and y axis is value of P